# Create Linq Expression for Sql Equivalent "column is null" in c# by creating linq query dynamically

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-expressions

I have a table with following schema:

```
  create table test 
  (
    foo1 nvarchar(4),
    foo2 nvarchar(30)
  )
  create unique index test_foo1 on test (foo1);
```

When created entity using Entity using EF, it generated a class like:

```
public class Test
{
  public string foo1 {get; set;}
  public string foo2 {get; set;}
}
```

So when editing this record, I am building dynamic expression tree like below to find if there is a database record for actually editing:

```
Expression combinedExpression = null;

            foreach (string propertyName in keyColumnNames)
            {
               var propertyInfo = typeof(Entity).GetProperty(propertyName);
               var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(entityWithKeyFieldsPopulated);
               var type = propertyInfo.PropertyType;


                Expression e1 = Expression.Property(pe, propertyName);
                Expression e2 = Expression.Constant(value, type);
                Expression e3 = Expression.Equal(e1, e2);

                if (combinedExpression == null)
                {
                    combinedExpression = e3;
                }
                else
                {
                    combinedExpression = Expression.AndAlso(combinedExpression, e3);
                }
            }

            return combinedExpression;
```

By doing this whenever I am editing entity "Test" and supplying "null" to property foo1 it is querying database as "select * from test where foo1 == null". How can I build expression that actually creates a where clause as "select *from test where foo1 is null" ?

Comment: Are you looking at the actual SQL query generated by EF, or are you just looking at the ToString() of the expression?

Comment: @DaveM I ran SQL Profiler to see what query it is generating. It generated foo1 == null not foo1 is null

Comment: What SQL Provider? When I test with MS SQL Server, `Expression.Equal` generates `column IS NULL`. If you make a lambda test, what SQL is generated (e.g. `db.Where(r => r.foo1 == null)`)?

Comment: @NetMage , MS SQL OLE DB. When i make a lambda test it generated db.Where(r => r.foo1 == null) and in sql profiler it generated as “from test where foo1 = null”

Comment: MS SQL OLE DB doesn't make sense to me. LINQ to SQL has a provider for MS SQL but what does OLEDB have to do with it? Or are you using LINQ to Datasets?

Comment: @NetMage, Sorry for the confusion it is MS SQL.

Comment: Have you used LINQPad? When I run tests on my MS SQL server with LINQ to SQL, I get "IS NULL" using a lambda.

Answer (score -1):

It might just be that the query processor is not generating an `foo1 is null` expression because `foo1` is in a unique index. It won't be null so it won't generate that expression.

I have some tables with columns declared not nullable and `where x.column == null` generates `where 0 = 1` in its place. It knows it will never be true. Perhaps the same is happening here?